# Codeigniter login with codeigniter-bcrypt

Tags: php, codeigniter, bcrypt

I am using codeigniter-bcrypt from https://github.com/dwightwatson/codeigniter-bcrypt, with codeigniter. I have a form that is submitting post data to my main controller. I then check via a model the DB for the record. I have used the

```
$hash = $this->bcrypt->hash_password($password);
```

To hash the password on account creation. And it works. Password is properly hashed in DB. Now however I am unsure of where to use the reverse to check if the password entered in the form to post is the same as the DB's hashed password.

```
if ($this->bcrypt->check_password($password, $stored_hash))
{
    // Password does match stored password.
}
else
{
    // Password does not match stored password.
}
```

My code in my model is

```
function getUserByLogin($login, $password) {        
    $this->db->where('login',$login);
    $this->db->where('password',$password);

    $result = $this->getUsers();

    if (count($result) > 0) {
        return $result[0];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
function getUsers() {
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

and my controller

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $login = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $user = $this -> user_model -> getUserByLogin($login, $password);
            $this -> saveUserToSession($user);
            $loggedIn = ($user == null ? false : true);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the password checking is correct as on the documentation. what problems did you encounter?

Comment: where to implement the check. I tried using it on the controller with the post data, that didn't seem to work, I then tried to check right after the DB query but the variables are objects at that point.

Comment: do the checking on the `model` that returns `true` or `false`. Obviously you're current query is not checking the for the username and password. Include the username and password on your query. so that you will get only the user that has both username and password, Not all

Comment: The above mentioned repo is not maintained now. and it is suggested that you don't use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't do:

```
  $this->db->where('password',$password);
```

You're checking for the actual raw password inside the DB.

You should get the hash from the database and then compare it to the user's password:

```
function getUserByLogin($login, $password) {        
    $this->db->where('login',$login);

    $result = $this->getUsers($password);

    if (!empty($result)) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
function getUsers($password) {
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        $result = $query->row_array();

        if ($this->bcrypt->check_password($password, $result['password'])) {
            //We're good
            return $result;
        } else {
            //Wrong password
            return array();
        }

    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what i had originally tried. I copied it into my code and it didnt seem to work.

Comment: small problem needed to capitalize the $result['Password'] to get the index to work. However the check_password doesnt seem to work. I have echoed the $password and $result['Password'] before the if and both have correct values, however $this->bcrypt->check_password doesnt seem to be correctly checking the values, always returns wrong

Comment: Thanks for the help here. This worked. Found the problem, I was storing my password variable in a varchar(64) field. Changed it to a varchar(128) and that actually allowed the full encrypted password to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

You should use default php hash function

```
$options = [ 'cost' => 12, ]; echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```