# how can I modify my login model to accept bcrypt?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to modify my login to accept bcrypt , but when I try retrieve my password from db i dont know how to retrieve .  i also need to return me as result an array. i have this so far.. i dont need to use libraries , i want do it with native functions

```
public function login($username,$password){
        $this->db->select('storelte_users.id,first_name,last_name,username,password,profile_id');
        $this->db->from('storelte_users');
        $this->db->join('storelte_profile', 'storelte_users.profile_id = storelte_profile.id ','inner');
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $salt = '$2y$11$XsCgn8hLtWL/jMKrwXLAkOk0qs2YehsD2NCAKrgrsyo7YKh.HvNhi';
        $this->db->where('password',hash('sha256', $password.$salt));
        $result = $this->db->get();
        if($result->num_rows() > 0){
            return $result->result_array();
        }else{
           return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

i was doing something lke this , but didnt work

```
public function login($username,$password){
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $account = $this->db->get('storelte_users')->row();
        if ($account =! NULL) {
            if (password_verify($password,$account->password)) {
                return $result->result_array();
            }else{
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

how could I modify my old code to accept bcrypt and return me an array?

Comment: You can check this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139473](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139473)

Answer (score 0):

Use Bcrypt Library Save below file in application/library/Bcrypt.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Bcrypt {
  private $rounds;
  public function __construct($params=array('rounds'=>7)) {


    $rounds = $params['rounds'];

    if(CRYPT_BLOWFISH != 1) {
      throw new Exception("bcrypt not supported in this installation. See http://php.net/crypt");
    }

    $this->rounds = $rounds;
  }

  public function hash($input) {
    $hash = crypt($input, $this->getSalt());

    if(strlen($hash) > 13)
      return $hash;

    return false;
  }

  public function verify($input, $existingHash) {
    $hash = crypt($input, $existingHash);
    return $hash === $existingHash;
  }

  private function getSalt() {
    $salt = sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $this->rounds);

    $bytes = $this->getRandomBytes(16);

    $salt .= $this->encodeBytes($bytes);

    return $salt;
  }

  private $randomState;
  private function getRandomBytes($count) {
    $bytes = '';

    if(function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes') &&
        (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) !== 'WIN')) { // OpenSSL slow on Win
      $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($count);
    }

    if($bytes === '' && @is_readable('/dev/urandom') &&
       ($hRand = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb')) !== FALSE) {
      $bytes = fread($hRand, $count);
      fclose($hRand);
    }

    if(strlen($bytes) < $count) {
      $bytes = '';

      if($this->randomState === null) {
        $this->randomState = microtime();
        if(function_exists('getmypid')) {
          $this->randomState .= getmypid();
        }
      }

      for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16) {
        $this->randomState = md5(microtime() . $this->randomState);

        if (PHP_VERSION >= '5') {
          $bytes .= md5($this->randomState, true);
        } else {
          $bytes .= pack('H*', md5($this->randomState));
        }
      }

      $bytes = substr($bytes, 0, $count);
    }

    return $bytes;
  }

  private function encodeBytes($input) {
    // The following is code from the PHP Password Hashing Framework
    $itoa64 = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    $output = '';
    $i = 0;
    do {
      $c1 = ord($input[$i++]);
      $output .= $itoa64[$c1 >> 2];
      $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4;
      if ($i >= 16) {
        $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
        break;
      }

      $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
      $c1 |= $c2 >> 4;
      $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
      $c1 = ($c2 & 0x0f) << 2;

      $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
      $c1 |= $c2 >> 6;
      $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
      $output .= $itoa64[$c2 & 0x3f];
    } while (1);

    return $output;
  }
}
/***** End of BCrypt.php ***********/
```

In Model You have to include bcrypt.php library and use:

```
$this->load->library('bcrypt',$rounds); //$rounds configuration can be as per your requirement.

$this->bcrypt->hash($password);
```

Verify the password:

```
$this->bcrypt->verify($password,$hash_password_db->password);
```

This library is working good with codeigniter 3.